# reflective relationship with jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose we have a "person" class and each person can have a collection of other persons as sons, and each person can have a collection of other persons as fathers so that we know for each person his or her sons and parents.
How can we model it with JPA annotations? 
I tried that, but it's if a son has only one father:

```
@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@ManyToOne
private Person parent;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="parent")
private Collection<Person> children;

// Getters, Setters, etc...
}
```

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve? Is something broken/missing? Do you get an error message?

Comment: This is basic O-O and nothing to do with JPA (which simply provides a way of persisting such relations)

Comment: suppose a son can have more than one father. how would you do it?
the example deals with the case where a son has only one father

Comment: a son can have more than 1 PARENT. Having 2 fathers ain't a possibility with biology (though it is with societal relationships"). If you want to model multiple parents then you have a Collection field for parents

Comment: I agree with you on the biological side of the problem. And also agree for the collections of parents, but in this case, what annotation is used? and what field would be used for mapping?

Comment: i think you need to go back to drawing board, and decide what you want. if you want to be possible for child to have multiple parents, then you need to change relation type to ManyToMany and create joining table

Comment: How to use manyToMany in this case ?